# Perl Script Not Liking Date Extension

Tags: perl, aix

why do I receive the error complaining about the parenthesis ?

sh: syntax error at line 1 : `)' unexpected

when adding this date extension to the new  file -- `mv abc abc$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`
for it seems that it doesn't like that last parenthesis

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# =========================================== #
# Script to watch POEDIACK file size
#
#                - Comments -
#
# script will check the file size of the POEDIACK file in
# $LAWDIR/$PLINE/edi/in.
# If it's > 1 gig, it will send notification via email
#
#
# =========================================== #

use strict;

use POSIX qw(strftime);

# get env vars from system
my $LAWDIR = @ENV{'LAWDIR'};
my $PLINE = @ENV{'PLINE'};
#my $email_file = "/lsf10/monitors/poediack.email";

my $curr_date = strftime('%m%d%Y', localtime);

my $ack_file = "$LAWDIR" . "/$PLINE" . "/edi/in/POEDIACK";
my $ack_location = "$LAWDIR" . "/$PLINE" . "/edi/in/";
my $mv_location = "$LAWDIR" . "/$PLINE" . "/edi/in/Z_files";

my $ack_file_limit = 10;
#my $ack_file_limit = 1000000000;
my $ack_file_size;

if( -e $ack_file)
{
        $ack_file_size = -s $ack_file;
        if ( $ack_file_size > $ack_file_limit )
        {
                `compress -vf $ack_file`;
                `mv $mv_location\$ack_file.Z $mv_location\$ack_file.Z.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`;
        }
}
else
{
        print "POEDIACK File not found: $ack_file\n";
}

### end perl script ###
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(` is being interpreted as a variable. It is [the group ID of the process](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar). You need to escape it.

And you probably *shouldn't* escape `$ack_file`.

```
  `mv $mv_location$ack_file.Z $mv_location$ack_file.Z.\$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`;
```

---

It's safer and faster to avoid complicated shell commands and use [`rename`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename) instead.

```
use autodie;

my $timestamp = strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime);
rename "$mv_location$ack_file.Z", "$mv_location$ack_file.Z.$timestamp";
```

---

Or use an [existing log rotator](https://github.com/lingtalfi/logrotator).